# How to convert JSON file into regular table DataFrame in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following JSON fields

```
{"constructorId":1,"constructorRef":"mclaren","name":"McLaren","nationality":"British","url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McLaren"}

{"constructorId":2,"constructorRef":"bmw_sauber","name":"BMW Sauber","nationality":"German","url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMW_Sauber"}
```

The following code produces the the following DataFrame:
I'm running the code on Databricks

```
df = (spark.read 
      .format(csv) \
      .schema(mySchema) \
      .load(dataPath)    
           )

  display(df)
```

[image]

However, I need the DataFrame to look like the following:

[image]

I believe the problem is because the JSON is nested, and I'm trying to convert to CSV. However, I do need to convert to CSV.

Is there code that I can apply to remove the nested feature of the JSON?

Comment: It seems that you can read the json directly with `spark.read.json(path)` not csv.

Comment: @Lamanus, thanks for getting back to me. I should have mentioned that I'm reading in a dataset that is a JSON file. Therefore, I need to read in the file as JSON and then I'm converting it to CSV. Basically, I need the dataset to be in CSV format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try:

```
someDF = spark.read.json(somepath)
```

Infer schema by default or supply your own, set in your case in pySpark multiLine to false.

```
someDF = spark.read.json(somepath, someschema, multiLine=False)
```

See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html

With schema inference:

```
df = spark.read.option("multiline","false").json("/FileStore/tables/SOabc2.txt")
df.printSchema()
df.show()
df.count()
```

returns:

```
root
 |-- constructorId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- constructorRef: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nationality: string (nullable = true)
 |-- url: string (nullable = true)

+-------------+--------------+----------+-----------+--------------------+
|constructorId|constructorRef|      name|nationality|                 url|
+-------------+--------------+----------+-----------+--------------------+
|            1|       mclaren|   McLaren|    British|http://en.wikiped...|
|            2|    bmw_sauber|BMW Sauber|     German|http://en.wikiped...|
+-------------+--------------+----------+-----------+--------------------+

Out[11]: 2
```

Comment: Hi bluephantom, I tried your suggestion as follows:
```df = (spark.read 
      .format(csv) \
      .schema(mySchema) \
      .option("multiLine", True) \
      .load(dataPath)    
           )```

But I got the same table

Comment: can u show all code pls

Comment: I will show all the code shortly, but I should point out that the JSON is single line, not multiline. Does that make a difference?

Comment: I mentioned that the JSON in the example was nested. It was a mistake to suggest its nested as its clearly not nested.

Comment: I find no issue with my code with schema inference.

Comment: I have no csv. remove that.

Comment: multiline - true causes indeed issues follow my example code.